# How to setup a read write privileged user in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-grant

How to setup a read write privileged user in SQL Server so that that user has read write access to the newly created database automatically

Comment: you may grant admin privilege to it, then it will automatically have the read write access.

Comment: Should this apply to all user databases - including those already created or just newly created ones? Also what version of SQL Server?

Comment: Yes this should be apply to all the user databases which are created in future and all the existing databases. I am using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition

Comment: You can do that on all version of SQL Server

Comment: liotims, how to perform this ?